# Why does the electronic shutter prone to diffraction?

Tags: diffraction, electronic-shutter

According to some comparisons I've read between mechanical and electronic shutters, the latter is prone to the diffraction of light, how so?

Answer (score 2):

**No, it's the opposite**, the edges of the mechanical shutter diffract light, while the electronic shutter is not affected because it does not exist; there is no physical element that might cause the diffraction.

The [answer by chulster here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/90554/32811) shows that the effect is only noticeable in very high contrast situations, like bright light sources (similarly to the well known star-like diffraction from the lens iris).